# SSIS Package fails with Runtime Interopservices Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, db2

I have this SSIS package that used to run fine until a month ago. It started to fail with the following error code, but it ran fine after I restarted the process again. I've tried running it all day today but to avail.

The code is taking everything from excel file and pumping it to IBM DB2 table. I know the error says that there is not enough storage, but I have another another SSIS task that is 5 times its size in terms of steps, but it runs flawlessly.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated!

> Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070008): Not
>   enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070008)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100.GetBLOBData(IDTSBuffer100
>   pIDTSBuffer, Int32 hRow, Int32 hCol, UInt32 dwOffset, UInt32 dwCount) 
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.GetString(Int32
>   columnIndex)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ADONETDestination.GetBufferDataAtCol(PipelineBuffer
>   buffer, Int32 iCol)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ADONETDestination.ProcessInput(Int32
>   inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr
>   bufferWirePacket)

Comment: Nope. It is a 32 bit.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to read the data and write into a raw file to make sure that the issue is related to the Excel data ?

Comment: Do you mean to write to a flat file or excel from excel(datasource)?

Comment: What you can do is cutting your dataflow in two peaces. 1 read from excel and store in a raw file. 2 read from raw file and insert into db2. This way you know which part is causing the trouble by eating up the resources.

Comment: I see, will try and let you know. Thank you so much.